# HTML Exercise from CodeAcademy

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
    </ul> 
    <ul>
      <li>Browse</li>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Oops, try again. The second li element should have text, for example: **browse**

```
<li>Browse</li>
```

Please help! I'm a beginner at HTML.

Comment: Still. I closed up the <ul>, it's like this: DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  
 <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
 </ul>
<ul>
  <li>Browse</li>  
</ul>  
  </body>
</html>

Comment: could it be that you just wrote `Browse` instead of `browse`?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the second `<ul>` element with it's closing tag: `</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
   </ul>
```

to close it up and you should be good I think

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what the problem is, but you likely forgot to close the tag.

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
</ul> 
<ul>
  <li>Browse</li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second "ul" list tag is also unnecessary. The "ul" tags specify that this is a list, and the "li" tags specify what each item in the list is.

```
<ul>
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Browse</li>
</ul>
```

Unless the prompt is telling you to make two list, in which case, the answer below is correct

```
<ul>
 <li>Item 1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>Browse</li>
</ul>
```